# we implement connection pooling ourselves, but why it always out of connection?

Tags: java, database, connection-pooling

Following is the source code:

```
//public class ConnectionPool implements Runnable
public class ConnectionPool {
    private static Logger loger_error = Logger.getLogger("error");
    // JDBC Driver name
    String driverName;

    // JDBC Connection URL
    String connectionURL;

    // Minimum size of the pool
    int connectionPoolSize;

    // Maximum size of the pool
    int connectionPoolMax;

    // Maximum number of uses for a single connection, or -1 for none
    int connectionUseCount;

    // Maximum connection idle time (in minutes)
    int connectionTimeout;

    // Additional JDBC properties
    String userName;

    String password;

    // The Connection pool. This is a vector of ConnectionObject
    // objects
    Vector pool;

    // The maximum number of simultaneous connections as reported
    // by the JDBC driver
    int maxConnections = -1;

    // Scheduler scheduler;

    // Timeout value
    public static int TIMEOUT_MS = 20000;

    /**
     * Initializes the ConnectionPool object using 'ConnectionPool.cfg' as the
     * configuration file
     * 
     * @return true if the ConnectionPool was initialized properly
     */
    /*
     * public boolean initialize() throws Exception { return
     * initialize("com/omh/jdbc/ConnectionPool.cfg"); }
     */

    /**
     * Initializes the ConnectionPool object with the specified configuration
     * file
     * 
     * @param config
     *            Configuration file name
     * @return true if the ConnectionPool was initialized properly
     */
    public void initialize(String driverName, String connectionURL,
            int connectionPoolSize, int connectionPoolMax,
            int connectionUseCount, int connectionTimeout, String userName,
            String password) throws Exception {
        this.driverName = driverName;
        this.connectionURL = connectionURL;
        this.connectionPoolSize = connectionPoolSize;
        this.connectionPoolMax = connectionPoolMax;
        this.connectionUseCount = connectionUseCount;
        this.connectionTimeout = connectionTimeout;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;

        createPool();

        // scheduler = new Scheduler();
        // scheduler.schedule(this, TIMEOUT_MS);

    }

    /**
     * Destroys the pool and it's contents. Closes any open JDBC connections and
     * frees all resources
     */
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            // Clear our pool
            if (pool != null) {
                // Loop throught the pool and close each connection
                for (int i = 0; i < pool.size(); i++) {
                    ((MangoDBConnection) pool.elementAt(i)).closeConnection();
                }
            }
            pool = null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets an available JDBC Connection. Connections will be created if
     * necessary, up to the maximum number of connections as specified in the
     * configuration file.
     * 
     * @return JDBC Connection, or null if the maximum number of connections has
     *         been exceeded
     */
    public synchronized MangoDBConnection getConnection() {
        // If there is no pool it must have been destroyed
        if (pool == null) {
            return null;
        }

        MangoDBConnection connectionObject = null;
        int poolSize = pool.size();

        // Get the next available connection
        for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; i++) {
            // Get the ConnectionObject from the pool
            MangoDBConnection co = (MangoDBConnection) pool.elementAt(i);

            // If this is a valid connection and it is not in use,
            // grab it
            if (co.isAvailable()) {
                connectionObject = co;
                break;
            }
        }

        // No more available connections. If we aren't at the
        // maximum number of connections, create a new entry
        // in the pool
        if (connectionObject == null) {
            if ((connectionPoolMax < 0)
                    || ((connectionPoolMax > 0) && (poolSize < connectionPoolMax))) {
                // Add a new connection.
                int i = addConnection();

                // If a new connection was created, use it
                if (i >= 0) {
                    connectionObject = (MangoDBConnection) pool.elementAt(i);
                }
            } else {
                LogManager.log("Maximum number of connections exceeded");
                loger_error.error("Maximum number of connections exceeded");
            }
        }

        // If we have a connection, set the last time accessed,
        // the use count, and the in use flag
        if (connectionObject != null) {
            connectionObject.use();
            connectionObject.touch();
        }

        return connectionObject;
    }

    /**
     * Places the connection back into the connection pool, or closes the
     * connection if the maximum use count has been reached
     * 
     * @param Connection
     *            object to close
     */

    public synchronized void releaseConnection(MangoDBConnection con) {
        removeFromPool(con);
    }

    public synchronized void release(MangoDBConnection con) {
        if ((connectionUseCount > 0)
                && (con.getUseCount() >= connectionUseCount)) {
            removeFromPool(con);
            // add new connection upon releasing one
            addConnection();
        } else {
            con.touch();
            con.free();
        }
        /*
         * // Find the connection in the pool int index = find(con);
         * System.out.println("close"); if (index != -1) { ConnectionObject co =
         * (ConnectionObject) pool.elementAt(index);
         *  // If the use count exceeds the max, remove it from // the pool. if
         * ((connectionUseCount > 0) && (co.useCount >= connectionUseCount)) {
         * trace("Connection use count exceeded"); removeFromPool(index); } else { //
         * Clear the use count and reset the time last used co.touch();
         * co.free(); } }
         */
    }

    /**
     * Prints the contents of the connection pool to the standard output device
     */
    public void printPool() {
        printPool(new PrintWriter(System.out));
    }

    /**
     * Prints the contents of the connection pool to the given PrintWriter
     */
    public void printPool(PrintWriter out) {
        out.println("--ConnectionPool--");
        if (pool != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pool.size(); i++) {
                MangoDBConnection co = (MangoDBConnection) pool.elementAt(i);
                out.println("" + i + "=" + co);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns an enumeration of the ConnectionObject objects that represent the
     * pool
     */
    public Enumeration getConnectionPoolObjects() {
        return pool.elements();
    }

    public int returnConnectionCount() {
        return connectionUseCount;
    }

    public int returnMaxPoolSize() {
        return connectionPoolMax;
    }

    public int returnInitPoolSize() {
        return connectionPoolSize;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the ConnectionObject from the pool at the given index
     * 
     * @param index
     *            Index into the pool vector
     */
    private synchronized void removeFromPool(MangoDBConnection con) {
        // Make sure the pool and index are valid
        if (pool != null) {
            con.closeConnection();
            pool.removeElement(con);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates the initial connection pool. A timer thread is also created so
     * that connection timeouts can be handled.
     * 
     * @return true if the pool was created
     */
    private void createPool() throws Exception {
        // Dump the parameters we are going to use for the pool.
        // We don't know what type of servlet environment we will
        // be running in - this may go to the console or it
        // may be redirected to a log file
        LogManager.log("JDBCDriver = " + driverName);
        LogManager.log("JDBCConnectionURL = " + connectionURL);
        LogManager.log("ConnectionPoolSize = " + connectionPoolSize);
        LogManager.log("ConnectionPoolMax = " + connectionPoolMax);
        LogManager.log("ConnectionUseCount = " + connectionUseCount);
        LogManager.log("ConnectionTimeout = " + connectionTimeout + " seconds");
        LogManager.log("Registering " + driverName);

        Driver d = (Driver) Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();

        // Create the vector for the pool
        pool = new Vector();

        // Bring the pool to the minimum size
        fillPool(connectionPoolSize);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new connection to the pool
     * 
     * @return Index of the new pool entry, or -1 if an error has occurred
     */
    public int addConnection() {
        int index = -1;

        try {
            // Calculate the new size of the pool
            int size = pool.size() + 1;

            // Create a new entry
            fillPool(size);

            // Set the index pointer to the new connection if one
            // was created
            if (size == pool.size()) {
                index = size - 1;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("SSSSSSS");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return index;
    }

    /**
     * Brings the pool to the given size
     */
    private synchronized void fillPool(int size) throws Exception {
        String userID = this.userName;
        String password = this.password;

        // userID = getPropertyIgnoreCase(JDBCProperties, "user");
        // password = getPropertyIgnoreCase(JDBCProperties, "password");

        // Loop while we need to create more connections
        while (pool.size() < size) {
            MangoDBConnection co = new MangoDBConnectionMSSQL();

            // Create the connection
            co.makeConnection(connectionURL, userID, password);

            // Do some sanity checking on the first connection in
            // the pool
            if (pool.size() == 0) {
                // Get the maximum number of simultaneous connections
                // as reported by the JDBC driver
                maxConnections = co.getMaxConnections();
            }

            // Give a warning if the size of the pool will exceed
            // the maximum number of connections allowed by the
            // JDBC driver
            if ((maxConnections > 0) && (size > maxConnections)) {
                LogManager
                        .log("WARNING: Size of pool will exceed safe maximum of "
                                + maxConnections);
            }

            // Clear the in use flag
            co.free();
            // Set the last access time
            co.touch();

            pool.addElement(co);
        }

    } // fillPool()

    /**
     * Gets a the named propery, ignoring case. Returns null if not found
     * 
     * @param p
     *            The property set
     * @param name
     *            The property name
     * @return The value of the propery, or null if not found
     */
    private String getPropertyIgnoreCase(Properties p, String name) {
        if ((p == null) || (name == null))
            return null;

        String value = null;

        // Get an enumeration of the property names
        Enumeration enumeration = p.propertyNames();

        // Loop through the enum, looking for the given property name
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String pName = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
            if (pName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                value = p.getProperty(pName);
                break;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Called by the timer each time a clock cycle expires. This gives us the
     * opportunity to timeout connections
     */
    /*
     * public synchronized void run() { // No pool means no work if (pool ==
     * null) { return; }
     *  // Get the current time in milliseconds long now =
     * System.currentTimeMillis();
     *  // Check for any expired connections and remove them for (int i =
     * pool.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ConnectionObject co = (ConnectionObject)
     * pool.elementAt(i);
     *  // If the connection is not in use and it has not been // used recently,
     * remove it if (!co.inUse) { if ((connectionTimeout > 0) && (co.lastAccess +
     * (connectionTimeout * 1000) < now)) { removeFromPool(i); } } }
     *  // Remove any connections that are no longer open for (int i =
     * pool.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ConnectionObject co = (ConnectionObject)
     * pool.elementAt(i); try { // If the connection is closed, remove it from
     * the pool if (co.con.isClosed()) { trace("Connection closed
     * unexpectedly"); removeFromPool(i); } } catch (Exception ex) { } }
     *  // Now ensure that the pool is still at it's minimum size try { if (pool !=
     * null) { if (pool.size() < connectionPoolSize) {
     * fillPool(connectionPoolSize); } } } catch (Exception ex) {
     * ex.printStackTrace(); }
     *  // Reschedule ourselves scheduler.schedule(this, TIMEOUT_MS); }
     */

}
```

Anyone have good idea ?
How to implement connection pooling?

Comment: gr8, you reinvented the wheel.

Comment: @MemoryLeak - what he means is that there many existing implementations of connection pooling, and that you would do better by using one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common cause for leakage of resources in a resource pool (like your connection pool) is that some client of the pool is failing to release the resources under some circumstances.  Here's an example:

```
Resource resource = pool.getResource();
...
// do stuff
...
pool.releaseResource(resource);
```

This will leak resources if an exception is thrown in the "do stuff" section and allowed to propagate.  A non-leaky version of the above is:

```
Resource resource = pool.getResource();
try {
    ... 
    // do stuff
    ...
} finally {
    pool.releaseResource(resource);
}
```

EDIT:  As @Adamski points out, there is no "magic bullet" solution that will solve this kind of problem.  The best that I can suggest is to do the following:

1. Search through your codebase to find all places where a resource is requested from the pool.  Then starting at each point, check for leaks and fix; e.g. based on the above pattern.
2. Create a test suite that exercise all of your request types and run it repeatedly against your service

One more thing.  Don't be tempted to try to "fix" the problem by using a finalizer to deal with lost resources.  That may make the problem seem to go away, only to reappear later when your system is heavily loaded, or **Someone Important** is watching you do a demo.

Comment: So how to get rid of this problem eternally

Comment: Following the approach Stephen C suggests (using a try-finally block) along with ensuring the thread borrowing the connection does not block indefinitely will prevent connection leakage.  There is no "magic bullet" to stop it from happening - It relies on the client writing good code!

Answer (score 2):

Just as suggestion database pool management can be tricky, if you have further needs like adding connection timeout or adding pool management strategy (may be the case if you have several several thread using the same connection).

So I would suggest to use open source solution such as the Apache DHCP or other open source solution. You will still have to properly close your connections (as Suggested by Stephen C) but it will be give you more flexibility, if you need to implement more complex stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the point in time (and the requesting thread?), when a connection is borrowed in getConnection(), and add a thread to remove them from the pool after some minutes. This could help you to find the culprit :)

You shouldn't close the connection, except there won't be any long going task. I would simply log this.